# Category on NSObject also works on Class

Tags: objective-c

So I have a category on NSObject called CustomCategory, as following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (CustomCategory)

-(BOOL)doSomething;

@end

#import "NSObject+CustomCategory.h"

@implementation NSObject (CustomCategory)

-(BOOL)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"Done");
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Ideally, this will work on an object like this:

```
NSObject* object = [NSObject new];
[object doSomething];
```

However, I found that it also works in this way with no problem:

```
[NSObject doSomething];
```

So I am wondering, since it is an instance method I have added through the category, why it also works on a Class?

Comment: Show the declaration and definition code of the Category.

Comment: by working you mean that it compiles or that it runs the code inside doSomething

Comment: All classes are NSObjects too (except maybe NSProxy).

Comment: @user3125367Almost. All root classes are their own classes. So every class that inherits from NSObject is an NSObject and every class that inherits from NSProxy is a NSProxy.

Comment: @zaph NSObject is not special, it is handled like any other root class.

Comment: Yes and root classes are special WRT the usual classes. Notice I deleted my comment prior to yours, I realized it was basically incorrect. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instance methods on NSObject are also class methods on NSObject.

This works because of the way Objective-C does dynamic dispatch. If you send a message to any object the method implementation is looked up in the objects class. If you send a message to a class then you are sending a regular message to the class object. There the implementation is looked up in the so called meta-class. The meta-classes are automatically generated by the compiler. Class methods are just instance methods of the meta-class. This is handled transparently by the compiler.

Inheritance also works on the meta-class level. So the meta-class for a class inherits from the meta-class of its superclass.  We have two parallel inheritance hierarchies there. Only root classes like NSObject are handled differently. There the meta-class can't inherit from the meta-class of the superclass as there is no superclass. For root classes the meta-class inherits from the root class itself.

And since class methods of a class are instance methods of its meta-class and NSObjects meta-class inherits from NSObject itself instance methods on NSObject are also class methods on NSObject.

Comment: s/NSObject/Root Class/g. There are other root classes, such as NSAtom, NSProxy, etc.

Comment: NSObject's meta-class IS NOT NSObject. It is definitely separate.

Comment: Yes, fixed this. It is not NSObject, it inherits from NSObject. Otherwise root classes couldn't have class methods at all.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, you are right. But the meta-class of NSObject inherits from NSObject. Fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

For reference to anyone looking for the actual location of this in the runtime source, it currently resides in [objc-runtime-new.mm](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm#866)'s `methodizeClass` function:

```
... snip...

// Root classes get bonus method implementations if they don't have 
// them already. These apply before category replacements.

if (cls->isRootMetaclass()) {
    // root metaclass
    addMethod(cls, SEL_initialize, (IMP)&objc_noop_imp, "", NO);
}

... snip ...
```

... And the `+initialize` method of a meta-class will add all of the method implementations from its instance and convert them into a class method.

And, contrary to what @Sven has been saying, NSObject's meta-class is not actually NSObject. A class always has a separate meta-class in the runtime, regardless of whether it is root or not.

Comment: Your snippet says nothing, it shows where +initialize from root metaclasses comes from. I admit, I was a little bit inaccurate, I just checked. The metaclass of NSObject is not NSObject, it inherits directly from NSObject. Each object has a class, and each class must have a superclass and there the the parallel inheritance hierarchies combine.

Answer (score -2):

Every `Class` in Objective C is internally an object, which means it's a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: Not quite. Meta-classes do NOT all inherit from `NSObject`, nor are they instances of `NSObject`. They're actually treated completely separately during method resolution to handle root-object cases.

Comment: True, every class is an object. But the class objects class is not automatically NSObject.
@RichardJ.RossIII: Meta-classes for any class that inherits from NSObject also inherit from NSObject. Root classes are their own meta-class.

Comment: @Sven but it is not an instance of `NSObject`, which makes this answer misleading. The true answer is that method resolution is handled separately for root classes, for legacy purposes.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The only difference is that root classes are their own metaclass. For every class that inherits from NSObject it's meta-class also inherits from NSObject.